# Why am I getting NullPointerException in liferay?

Tags: java, liferay

I am getting a `NullPointerException` on the following line:

```
originalStrutsPortletAction.processAction(
                    originalStrutsPortletAction, portletConfig, actionRequest,
                        actionResponse);
```

I am printing all the values:

```
System.out.println(originalStrutsPortletAction);
System.out.println(portletConfig);
System.out.println(actionRequest);
System.out.println(actionResponse);
```

**Output:**

```
com.liferay.portal.struts.StrutsPortletActionAdapter@2f20c4be
com.liferay.portlet.PortletConfigImpl@5f4268dd
com.liferay.portlet.ActionRequestImpl@1054ae1e
com.liferay.portlet.ActionResponseImpl@27733bf2
```

So why am I getting `NullPointerException`? Please help.Thanks in advance.
The full stack trace is as follows:-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portlet.login.action.LoginAction.login(LoginAction.java:196)
    at com.liferay.portlet.login.action.LoginAction.processAction(LoginAction.java:93)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.StrutsPortletActionAdapter.processAction(StrutsPortletActionAdapter.java:60)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.struts.BaseStrutsPortletAction.processAction(BaseStrutsPortletAction.java:44)
    at com.abhishek.ExampleLoginAction.check(ExampleLoginAction.java:185)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.otpCheck_jsp._jspService(otpCheck_jsp.java:71)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor503.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy660.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: What is that `originalStrutsPortletAction`? Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: Your parameters are not `null`, as you have printed all. Might be that `processAction` throwing `npe`.

Comment: What version of Liferay are you using?

Comment: Are you sure that you look at the source code corresponding to your version of Liferay?

Comment: I am using liferay version 6.2

Comment: Can you look at your portal source of file `LoginAction.java:196` and tell what is there?

Comment: Are you sure you know what you're doing ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: You don't get a NullpointerException at that location- at least not according to the stacktrace you post. Liferay's LoginAction does not have an originalStrutsAction. In case you're using 6.2 GA5, [this is the code](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/login/action/LoginAction.java#L196) that throws the NullpointerException. Why? That's not what you asked.

Or, to phrase it differently: You're getting a NullpointerException because you dereference a Nullpointer. You'll just need to identify where you actually get it. The stacktrace helps. Who knows what your ExampleLoginAction does before it calls the line that you're posting...

Comment: The same function originalStrutsPortletAction.processAction(
                    originalStrutsPortletAction, portletConfig, actionRequest,
                        actionResponse) is working fine when called from one function but not working when called from another function.Although the parameter values are same in both calls.

Comment: I would question this by saying "obviously not". You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and change your question

Comment: No it's happening. I am amazed at liferay working. You can see here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39409739/same-function-working-differently-when-called-from-two-separate-functions-with-s